# problem with apostrophe

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the mysql. In a project there is a field for user edit. If the name contains character like 's then while save the record it atomatically inserts '\' character before the apostrophe and name becomes xyz\'s. Next time agin while saving it inserts another such characters and name becomes xyz\'s. 
Is there any solution?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You most probably have [magic_quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) directive turned on (which shouldn't). It automatically adds a backslash before quotes, so if you're using mysql_real_escape_string it will be added twice. If you're not using mysql_real_escape_string, well..just [shame on you!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

```
function escape($field)
{
if(magic_quotes_gpc())
{
  $field = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($field));
}
else
{
  $field = mysql_real_escape_string($field);
}
}
```

Then just do (be sure to have an open connection before calling the function, or mysql_real_escape_string() returns FALSE)

```
$name = escape($_POST['name']);
```

Or simply turn it off from you PHP ini:

```
ini_set('magic_quotes_gpc',0);
```

**Better yet**, use  [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and stop worrying about escaping and SQL injections!

Answer (score 0):

You have Magic Quotes turned on.

Please read the manual section on [disabling Magic Quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php)